# Can you be sent to Reading Railroad without passing Go?

Tags: monopoly

In Monopoly, there is a Chance card that reads :

> Take a ride on the Reading. Advance token and if you pass Go, collect
> $200

Given that there is no legal way that you could reach Reading Railroad from a Chance square **without** passing Go, why is it specified on the card?

Is there a historic rule that may have changed ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes, it can happen...**

There are 2 cases that explain the wording of this card. These cases reveal that it is possible to be sent to Reading Railroad by a Chance card from a square other than a Chance square.

**Case 1 Original USA game**

According to [World of Monopoly](http://www.worldofmonopoly.com/northamerica/usa/country/info/candcc-index.php), these (first?) four versions of Monopoly contained this Community Chest card : **«Pay $10 fine or take a Chance»**

> Darrow White Box, Darrow Black Box, Parker Bros 1935 Plain, Parker
> Bros 1935-36 Plain

[image: Pay a $10.00 Fine or take "Chance"]

This means that you could be sent to Reading Railroad by a Chance card from the Community Chest square between Mediterranean Avenue and Baltic Avenue, and NOT pass Go.

According to [EnAcademic.com](https://enacademic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/7021822), this Community Chest card has been omitted from the US editions since 1936.

**Case 2 Blame Canada**

Again, according to [World Of Monopoly](http://worldofmonopoly.com/albert/canada_uk.htm),

> Edition:  “Mini box”, with separate board - Atlantic City Publisher:
> Parker Bros. Inc/The Copp Clark Co.Ltd. - ±1946 ... Reg. U.S. Patent
> Office Canadian Registration M.S. 19-5674 U.S.  Patents 1.509.312
> ---2.026.082  **Patented Canada**.1936 ---- 362.124 ...
>
> «Curiously, the rules of this game (in English and French) contain a
> provision that a player rolling a 3 may take a Chance or Community
> Chest card instead of making his move.»

I remember playing with this rule in the 1950s, but I always remembered it as a house rule. It appears that it was official, in Canada.

Therefore, if you rolled a 3 while on Mediterranean Avenue, Community Chest(1), Baltic Avenue or Income Tax, you could elect to not play it, take a Chance card, and be sent to Reading Railroad by that card, without passing Go.

**Conclusion**

In either case, it would be possible to be sent to Reading Railroad, by a Chance card, from a square other than Chance, and not pass Go. And that is why the phrase «... if you pass GO, collect $200» was required on the Chance card in those days. The phrase just was not dropped when no longer required.

Comment: I'll note that your "that is why" conclusion here is also an opinion.

Comment: A valid point...

Answer (score 1):

It's just following standard templating for cards that move the tokens.

Perhaps the designer(s) felt alternate wordings would be unclear (perhaps lead to people trying to collect $400 or not collecting at all).

Comment: That is an opinion. I expect there would be facts that explain the wording.

Comment: That it follows standard templating is a fact. The bit I prefaced with "perhaps" is conjecture, sure.